# Element-wise comparison of two Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```py
>>> db
array([[[[   48.4473645 ,  -49.42020132,  -59.52442657,  199.95277333,
            131.69291221,  -69.15365214, -155.71041334,   16.42950385]]]])

>>> db_test
array([[[[   48.4473645 ,  -49.42020132,  -59.52442657,  199.95277333,
            131.69291221,  -69.15365214, -155.71041334,   16.42950385]]]])

>>> db == db_test
array([[[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]]])
```

It seems that these two arrays are identical, but they aren't. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Please provide how you get db and db_test

Comment: can you print type(db[0][0][0]) and type(db_test[0][0][0])

Comment: Hello Walentines44, thank you very much for your question! Please provide your code and data as text and not as image so it is reproducible for users. Please consider looking here for guidance: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank you!

Comment: Try `np.isclose`.  Floats often don't test exactly.

Comment: i get True using np.isclose

Comment: If using "np.isclose" solved your problem, please mark your question as "closed", so others know it is closed.

Comment: To read more about the issue of floating point comparison in Python, visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python.
Consider if your question is a duplicate of that one.